# Validating third variable on difference between 2 other variables in cakephp

Tags: validation, cakephp

I can't get my head around this one.  I want to validate whether a third variable on a cakephp form is less than or equal to the difference between two other variables on the form.  Has anyone tackled this or similar?

Paul

here is some code to show what I have done:

```
public function lessThanEqualTo($check, $otherfield) {
    $value = array_values($check);
    $compareTo = $this->data[$this->name][$otherfield];
    if (!Validation::comparison($value[0], 'lessorequal', $compareTo)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }        
}

public function numDifference($startnumber, $usednumber) {
    $sn = int($this->data[$this->name][$startnumber]);
    $un = int($this->data[$this->name][$usednumber]);
    return ($sn - $un);
}
```

Model contains validation: but the second rule is plain wrong, I have tried a number of things, but I am just coming up with rubbish:

```
public $validate = array(

    'ag1_compl_dist_num'=>array(
        'rule' => array('lessThanEqualTo','ag1_compl_start_number'),
        'message' => 'Value must be less than starting number',
        'allowEmpty' => true,
        'required' => false
    ),
    'ag1_compl_remain' => array(
        'rule' => array('lessThanEqualTo','numDifference'),
        'message' => 'Value must be less than difference between numbers',
        'allowEmpty' => true,
        'required' => false
    )

);
```

Clearly, the call to numDifference should have something that identifies which two numbers to work out the difference between..

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes, I can validate that one variable is (say) less than or equal to another, using cakephp validation rules and validation methods.  But I can't see how to pass the result of a method (that works out the difference between two other variables) into the rule calling the method to check if the third field is less than or equal to this differnece.  I would put up some code, but it won't even run my effort is so poor!

Comment: Could you also show how are you adding your validators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
'rule' => array('lessThanEqualTo','numDifference')
```

And then in your `lessThanEqualTo` function `$compareTo = $this->data[$this->name][$otherfield];`, you will look for `numDifference` field in your `data` object, which does not exist.

One way would be to create a `lessThanEqualToDiff` method like this:

```
public function lessThanEqualToDiff ($check, $startfield, $usedfield) {
    $value = array_values($check);
    $sn = intval($this->data[$this->name][$startfield]);
    $un = intval($this->data[$this->name][$usedfield]);
    return Validation::comparison($value[0], 'lessorequal', $sn - $un) ;
}
```

Then your rule:

```
public $validate = array(
    'ag1_compl_remain' => array(
        'rule' => array('lessThanEqualToDiff', 'ag1_compl_start_number', 'ag1_compl_used_number'),
        'message' => 'Value must be less than difference between numbers',
        'allowEmpty' => true,
        'required' => false
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this Holt, it makes perfect sense.  I will give this a try and come back to show this solution works.

Comment: Yes, this worked (there was an error in the use of the int function in php, but that was inherited from my original request.

Answer (score 0):

So, the validation method should be like this:

```
public function lessThanEqualToDiff ($check, $startfield, $usedfield) {
$value = array_values($check);
$sn = (int)$this->data[$this->name][$startfield];
$un = (int)$this->data[$this->name][$usedfield]
return Validation::comparison($value[0], 'lessorequal', $sn - $un) ;
```

}

to use the php int feature correctly.  Thanks to Holt and marian0 for their help.